# Error: Microsoft.HostIntegration.SNA.Session.SessionException: The underlying SNA session failed. The application must release the session

Tags: .net, session, mainframe

I have a .NET application that uses Microsoft Host Integration Server 2016 to get data from an IBM mainframe computer. The application is setup to run on a schedule every hour to process a number of transactions. For each transaction, it connects to the remote mainframe, login, get the data, and then disconnect.
I sometimes get the error: "Microsoft.HostIntegration.SNA.Session.SessionException: The underlying SNA session failed. The application must release the session". Would appreciate if anyone has experienced with this error and let me know how to handle it?

Thanks

Comment: What messages do the mainframe logs have around the time of the failure?

Answer (score 2):

The SessionException has an ErrorCode Property that has a SessionStatus value.   The specific value should provide more information about the local status which should be one of the values documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.hostintegration.sna.session.sessionstatus?view=his-dotnet)

This information coupled with the corresponding message from the z/OS system log will give you the information to understand the nature of the failure.  The message will give you a more complete picture.  Extracting the name of your Logical Unit (LU) will make correlation easier but just using the time might be enough.

The LU Name can be found in the .Session.SessionStatus object in the property `LogicalUnitName` and the host you are connected to in the `ServerName` property.

The z/OS system log will most likely have a message that likely starts with IST will provide a sense code that represents what VTAM thinks is going on.

You can find these documented [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/servers/resourcelink/svc00100.nsf/pages/zOSV2R3sc273648/$file/cs3cod0_v2r3.pdf) as well as in other manuals; these codes do not change frequently.  These are eight characters in length with the first four characters being a category and the last four may provide additional information.

Update your question with more diagnostic information if you need further help as “session failed” is too generic to provide a specific answer to.